# Components of a vector product as an antisymmetrical rank 2 tensor

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors

So I'm reading Landau and Lifshitz' Theory of Elasticity (https://archive.org/details/TheoryOfElasticity) and they have done, among (many) other things, something I simply don't understand.

On page 5, they start talking about the moment of force, defined I guess as **F**x**r**. They have a little footnote at the bottom saying you can write **the components of a vector product as an antisymmetrical tensor of rank two**.

I...really really don't know what the hell they are talking about, or how that is possible. Can someone help?

Comment: So folks have a starting point for their answers (and so those answers don't go over your head or explain stuff you already know): do you know what a tensor is? An antisymmetric tensor?  A tensor of rank two?

Comment: I more or less know what a tensor is, antisymmetric tensors are A_{ij} = -A_{ji}. I'll admit the subtle difference between a matrix and a rank 2 tensor is a little lost on me.


What I really don't understand is **how** they are generating a tensor from a cross product. Like, in general that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the top.  If you have any programming background, then the following might make some more sense to you:

A tensor is merely a function that is *linear* on each of its arguments and produces a number.  For instance, let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.  That is, for any vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$, $f(v)$ is some real number.  If $f$ is linear--that is, for another vector $w$, $f(v) + f(w) = f(v+w)$ and other stuff--then $f$ is also a tensor.

In physics parlance, a "tensor of rank two" means "a tensor that is a function of two arguments."  So we have some tensor $A: \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, or $A(v,w)$ is a number.

How does this connect with index notation?  Because of linearity, you can fully describe $A(v,w)$ for any vectors $v,w$ by examining $A(e_i, e_j)$, where $e_i$ and $e_j$ are stand-ins for basis vectors.  Explicitly, it's this:

$$A(v,w) = \sum_{i,j} v^i w^j A(e_i, e_j)$$

And it is typical to write $A_{ij} = A(e_i, e_j)$.

You mention being lost on the subtle difference between a matrix and a rank 2 tensor here.  I would say it's this: for a rank-2 tensor, you *can* write the rules above entirely in terms of matrix multiplication.  But you are not required to do so.

(Nb. A tensor's components also have particular transformation laws under change of basis, but for the purposes of this answer, I'm taking the position that such transformations are passive transformations, and that these different sets of components represent the same geometric object merely in different bases.  I'm well aware that active and passive transformations are indistinguishable, but I feel this point is out of scope for this answer.)

---

Now, what does this have to do with the cross product?

Consider $f(v,w) = v \cdot (F \times w)$ for vectors $v, F, w$.  We've defined some *function* $f$, but we have not proved this is a tensor.  Yet.

All we need do is prove whether $f$ is linear in both arguments.  Is it?

Let $c$ be another vector and $\alpha$ a scalar.  Then...

Is it true that $f(v+c,w) = f(v,w) + f(c,w)?$  Yes.  See that $(v+c) \cdot (F \times w) = v \cdot (F \times w) + c \cdot (F \times w)$.

Is it true that $f(v, w+c) = f(v,w) + f(v,c)$? Again, yes. This follows from distributivity of the cross product over addition.

Is it true that $f(\alpha v, w) = \alpha f(v,w)$?  That $f(v,\alpha w) = \alpha f(v,w)$? Again, yes and yes.  Both the dot and cross products respect scalar multiplication.

Thus, $f$ is linear in both arguments, and it is therefore a tensor (of rank 2, in physics parlance).

---

Thus far, I've proven that for any vector $F$, there is a tensor $f$ such that $f(v,w) = v \cdot (F \times w)$.  Using this prescription, we can extract the components:

$$f_{ij} = e_i \cdot (F \times e_j)$$

For instance, $f_{xy} = \hat x \cdot (F \times \hat y) = -F^z$ in Cartesian coordinates.

As I mentioned earlier, one can use matrices and matrix multiplication to facilitate computation with rank-2 tensors.  The resulting matrix representation would look like this:

$$[f] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -F^z & F^y \\ F^z & 0 & -F^x \\ -F^y & F^x & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

And then we would just compute $f(v,w) = [v]^T [f] [w]$.

Comment: Hey so I'm going to go over this carefully right now, but just skimming it sort of there are a couple points I'm confused about that you should know.


First of all, I'm not at all familiar with the superscript notation. I've never really used it and never really understood it. I may just end up writing in a few things after of gone over this carefully to make sure I'm doing it right, but I wouldn't mind it either if you either stuck to subscript only notation or gave a little explanation of superscript notation within the context of your answer.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure I understand the relevance, or even necessarily the meaning of the relation 

$A(v,w) = \sum_{ij} v^iw^i A(e_i,e_j) $

Specifically, I'm confused about why this "fully describes" A(v,w), and what exactly the superscript notation means.

Comment: Superscript vs. subscripts: components written with superscripts go with the usual tangent basis vectors, which may be denoted $e_i$ for instance. These are not necessarily unit (but they are in Cartesian coordinates), hence I did not use hats with them. The tangent basis vectors are the vectors *tangent* (parallel) to coordinate lines. - Components with subscripts go with the *cotangent* basis vectors, which are normal ("cotangent") to surfaces of constant coordinate. In Cartesian coordinates, the tangent and cotangent basis vectors are identical, and subscripts are the same as superscripts.

Comment: The tensor $A(v,w)$ is fully described by the total set of the components $A_{ij}$ because you can write $A(v,w) = \sum_{i,j} v^i w^j A_{ij}$ for any $v,w$. I'm trying to get across that you do not need to know $A(v,w)$ for every possible $v$ and $w$. Using the basis vectors is enough because of linearity.

Comment: (Sorry I'll read your comments in a sec bear with me) Okay so I think I get the principle of what your'e trying to do, but I'm still not sure what L\&L did. 

Thinking about L\&L, I feel it would be appropriate to define 
$M_{ik} = \hat{e}_1 \cdot [\mathbf{F}\times(x_k\hat{e}_k)]$, but this would give the matrix 

$$[M] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -F_3x_2 & F_2x_3 \\ F_3x_1 & 0 & -F_1x_3 \\ -F_2x_1 & F_1x_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: On the other hand,  Landau \& Lifshitz would seem to claim, from $M_{ik} = F_ix_k - F_k x_i$, that it should be 

$$[M] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & F_1x_2-F_2x_1 & F_1x_3-F_3x_1 \\F_2x_1-F_1x_2& 0 & F_2x_3-F_3x_2\\ F_3x_1-F_1x_3& F_3x_2-F_2x_3& 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Which is, as you can see, pretty different from what the definition $M_{ik} = \hat{e}_1 \cdot [\mathbf{F}\times(x_k\hat{e}_k)]$ gives. 

Anyway also it seems almost as though Landau \& Lifshitz are not taking the dot product, i.e. keeping only the cross product term, but I'm not really sure how to get their exact definition out.

Comment: If Landau and Lifshitz wrote exactly what you wrote, then what they said is unclear or misleading. With any vector $F$ there is a rank-2 tensor $f$ defined as I defined it (with no reference to $r$). The cross product $F \times r$ can be written in terms of the $f_{ij}$ as $\sum_j f_{ij} x^j$. This is without a doubt what L&L *mean*, even though what they say seems to imply otherwise.

Comment: I mean, I linked to the book so you can read it and check it out. But they literally state the "moment of force" tensor as being $M_{ik} = F_ix_k - F_kx_i$ (there is an integral over it, but that's only because F, as L&L have defined it, is a variational/differential force).

Comment: Apply the method I have described to $F \times r$ instead of just $F$.